# API calls forced even with all intents enabled

Tags: discord.py

I've been having an issue recently with getter methods from different objects in discordpy, in this example I'm using `discord.Guild`

```py
guild = await bot.fetch_guild(key)  # API call used because getter returns nothing

categories = guild.categories  # returns empty list
```

[image: attributes in the Guild object]

Intents are all enabled, I used `discord.Intents.all()`.

Privileged gateway intents are also all enabled in [Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications).

Can someone help me with this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Where are you calling this?

Comment: this is being called in a tasks.loop that runs every 5 minutes

Comment: Are you waiting until the bot is ready before starting the task? (``wait_until_ready``)

Comment: I am starting the task in the on_ready event, so that should only run when the bot is ready.

Comment: from [discordpy docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=fetch_guild#discord.ext.commands.Bot.fetch_guild) , `fetch_guild()` limits possibilities and you should prefer `get_guild()`.

Comment: @pluckplk but get_guild doesn't return anything...

Comment: Are you sure of that `key` argument then ?

Comment: when I use the API call, I get the guild that I'm looking for, I just don't get the channels (because as you mentioned, it limits possibilities)

Comment: There is, apparently, no reason that get_guild() doesn't work. Therefore, I'd go check what that key contains with a `print(str(key))` previous to the `get_guild()`, and compare the ID I could get with the ID of the guild. We have no clue how you fill that `key` argument, maybe you got it by `ctx.message.guild` that returns the name of a guild, not an ID.

Comment: Also, if you read docs a little more, you'll see fetch_guild() raises error that you need to `try` and `catch` but it always returns an guild. get_guild doesn't raise error, but if the guild ID is invalid it returns None instead.

Comment: The key was correct... however it was a string. I converted it to an integer and it worked.
Quite careless of me not to check that it was a string

I also got confused by the fact that the API call always returned a guild. I just checked the different results given when passing `key` as  a string and as integer and they're different.